# Extending sets to extensional sets

Tags: set-theory

Let us say a set $X$ is extensional if, for all distinct $a,b$ in $X$, $X$ contains a member of the symmetric difference of $a$ and $b$. (id est $\langle X,=,\in\rangle$ is a model of the axiom of extensionality).

My question is: ``Does every finite set have a finite extensional superset?''

I thought the answer should be an easy `yes' but i haven't been able to find a proof (even allowing myself both foundation and choice!) and i'm now beginning to doubt it.   Of course now that i have posted this question i shall see the answer immediately!  At some point, if people are interested, i shall narrate how this question arose....

Comment: I'm interested as to how the question arose...

Comment: Too long a story to fit in here!  But it's to do with finding substructures elementary for AE sentences.  Pick up a tuple of instances of ∀ vbls and blow them up into an extensional substructure. If it satisfies the AE sentence then there will be witnesses to the  ∃ vbls and you can copy them up to the original model.   The question is: does TZT (typed set theory with types indexed by Z) decide all AE sentences in the language of type theory.  At some point i will need to know your real name becos i will want to attribute this to you when i write this up! you can email me at tf@dpmms.cam.ac.uk

Answer (score 26):

No, here is a counterexample (I thought about this question some time ago and also expected it would be easy to prove, but in the end couldn't do it, and arrived at this counterexample): We will construct a set $p = \{x, y\}$ with no extensional finite superset. First define
a set $n^*$ for $n<\omega$ recursively by:

$0^* = \emptyset$,

$1^* = \{0^*\}$,

$2^* = \{1^*\}$,

$3^* = \{0^*, 2^*\}$,

$4^* = \{1^*, 3^*\}$,

etc, so

$(2n+1)^* = \{0^*, 2^*, \ldots, (2n)^*\}$,

$(2n+2)^* = \{1^*, 3^*, \ldots, (2n+1)^*\}$.

Then let

$x = \{0^*, 2^*, \ldots, (2n)^*, \ldots \}$

$y = \{1^*, 3^*, \ldots, (2n+1)^*, \ldots \}$

and $p = \{x, y\}$.

Suppose that $p \subseteq q$ and $q$ is finite and extensional.
There must be some $n^*$ in $q$, in order to distinguish between $x$ and $y$.
Let $N$ be largest such that $N^*$ is in $q$.
If $N = 2n+1$ then $N^* \cap q = x \cap q$, but then $q$ is not extensional.
Likewise with $y$ if $N = 2n$. Contradiction.

(Remark: e.g. let $q = \{x, y, 0^*\}$. Then $q$ is "weakly extensional",
meaning that there are no membership-automorphisms of $q$.)

Comment: Wow!   Thank you very much!!  What made you interested in this question, BTW..?

Comment: No problem. I was just thinking about large cardinals / elementary embeddings in the absence of choice. If the statement had in fact been proveable, then finite extensional sets would have been a convenient indexing for the family of measures derived from an elementary embedding (i.e. associated to an extender). Under choice it is common to use finite sequences of ordinals, but without choice that needn't work. I first thought finite extensional sets work, until noticing this issue. But fortunately there are other options that do work for such indexing.

Comment: Thanks again.  I too am interested in large cardinals without choice (not least becos of my interest in NF). Your counterexample is in some sense best possible, and - perhaps unsurprisingly - it's unstratified and can't obviously be reproduced in NF.  So perhaps the conjecture is consistent with NF!  For me the proposition arose from my study of universal-existential sentences in simply typed set theory (TST/TZT).  The coresponding assertion for the strongly typed theory is actually provable - because one doesn't need witnesses for the symmetric difference for two sets not at the same level.

Comment: @Farmer: Regarding the indexing of measures, wouldn't the right thing be indexing with some finite subsets of a sufficiently large $V_\alpha$ or something like that?